# Looking for WordPress Slideshow Gallery Plugin

Tags: gallery

I'm looking to see if there is already a plugin that does a gallery slide show like Huffington Post does where it shows either one image or video then you click next to see the next one. There is no need for a rating system. I'm hoping there is so I don't have to figure out how to make one :)

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/lee-brenner/viral-videos-2010_b_801501.html

Other examples:

http://bleacherreport.com/articles/437878-larissa-riquelme-and-the-25-hottest-superfan-photoshoots/page/1

http://www.businessinsider.com/super-bowl-commercials-super-bowl-xlv-2011-2#volkswagen--the-force-1

**FOUND A SOLUTION USING NEXTGEN:**
Actually someone found this post and they found the solution :)
http://gregrickaby.com/2010/07/add-an-anchor-to-nextgen-gallery-image-browser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOUND A SOLUTION USING NEXTGEN:** Actually someone found this post and they found the solution :) http://gregrickaby.com/2010/07/add-an-anchor-to-nextgen-gallery-image-browser.html